# iOS- swift 3- Nested sorting and union with flatmap, map, filter or formUnion

Tags: dictionary, filter, swift3, closures, flatmap

```
class Flight{
    var name:String?
    var vocabulary:Vocabulary?
}


class Vocabulary{
    var seatMapPlan:[Plan] = []
    var foodPlan:[Plan] = []
}

class Plan{
    var planName:String?
    var planId:String?
}


var flightList:[Flight] = []
var plan1 = Plan()
plan1.planId = "planId1"
plan1.planName = "Planname1"

var plan2 = Plan()
plan2.planId = "planId2"
plan2.planName = "Planname2"

var plan3 = Plan()
plan3.planId = "planId3"
plan3.planName = "Planname3"

var plan4 = Plan()
plan4.planId = "planId4"
plan4.planName = "Planname4"

var plan5 = Plan()
plan5.planId = "planId5"
plan5.planName = "Planname5"

var plan6 = Plan()
plan6.planId = "planId6"
plan6.planName = "Planname6"

var flight1 = Flight()
flight1.name = "Flight1"
flight1.vocabulary = Vocabulary()
flight1.vocabulary?.seatMapPlan = [plan1, plan2]
flight1.vocabulary?.foodPlan = [plan3, plan4, plan5]


var flight2 = Flight()
flight2.name = "Flight2"
flight2.vocabulary = Vocabulary()
flight2.vocabulary?.seatMapPlan = [plan2, plan3]
flight2.vocabulary?.foodPlan = [plan3, plan4, plan5]

flightList=[flight1, flight2]
```

Problem 1:
I want to use flatmap,filter,custom unique func or Sets.formUnion to achieve a union of seatMapPlans. For this particular example it is

```
seatMapUnion = [plan1,plan2,plan3]
```

Because of nesting with the help of answered questions I am unable to achieve this.
Please give me a combination of filter,flatMap and map for resolving this particular problem.

Problem 2:
I have vice-versa scenarios too were i have to sort this array flightList on basis of plan(plan1 or multiple) selected. I want to sort this on basis of filter and map, but the nesting is making it difficult to achieve.
e.g. 1: 
if the search parameter is plan1 for seatMapPlan. Then the result is flight1.

e.g. 2:
And if the search parameter is plan2 for seatMapPlan. Then the result is flight1,flight2.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and add init methods with parameters.

Comment: Gnasher729 in actual environment they are json parsed and highly nested. This is just for asking question.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem I would use sets. So first make `Plan` implement `Hashable` :

```
class Plan : Hashable {
    var planName:String?
    var planId:String?

    public var hashValue: Int { return planName?.hashValue ?? 0 }
    public static func ==(lhs: Plan, rhs: Plan) -> Bool { return lhs.planId == rhs.planId }
}
```

Then it's straightforward :

```
let set1 = Set<Plan>(flight1.vocabulary!.seatMapPlan)
let set2 = Set<Plan>(flight2.vocabulary!.seatMapPlan)

let union = set1.union(set2)
print(union.map { $0.planName! } )
```

It'll print:

```
["Planname2", "Planname1", "Planname3"]
```

Not sure I understand your second problem.

Comment: var planArray = flightlList.flatMap{$0.vocabulary!.seatMapPlan}

;
var unionArray = Array(Set(planArray))